# Why has a variable the type 'unknown' again after reassignment

Tags: typescript

Why `value` is of type `unknown` again after assigning a `string` to it?

[Example in TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.7.4#code/FAMwrgdgxgLglgewgAgKYA8CGBbADgG1QAoBKALmQCMEFDMUBvYZZQmZAN03zFQsgDWEBAHcUAXmQByAM4JsqGAAs4EAOZTkAei3JsmAJ6VUyJagBOJuDORyFycNHhJkUbvgA0yESqhLkljBg5hA2gsJiwMAAkHAgyEQAhEQwBrioCPFcPCbiedIyMOaqGiTIAGTlyMmp6Zmc3LzIeZJSEGDYxuZSJGVM0dGBwSgg3DKoMQC%20USzZTTq2RSXIAD7I7Z0WMw05zdIwqIVS23MmC%20GiENtDIchFvMDTQA)

```js
function example(): boolean {
  let value: unknown = 'something' // maybe here is some function call, which returns unknown

  if (!(typeof value === 'string') && !(typeof value === 'number')) {
    return false
  }

  value // string | number

  value = 'test'

  value // unknown

  return true
}
```

Comment: That's just how it was designed. They didn't expect you to assign it a different value after checking it so they didn't add anything to check if the given value is assignable to the narrowed value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've just run into the issue in [microsoft/TypeScript#27706](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27706), which is currently marked as a feature request and not a bug.  But it's definitely confusing.

---

TypeScript performs [narrowing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html) based on some heuristic rules. Some of these rules are able to narrow values of [the `unknown` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#unknown), while others only work properly on values of [union types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types).  (And `unknown` is not a union).

For example, [`typeof` type guards](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#typeof-type-guards) work on `unknown`, as mentioned in [microsoft/TypeScript#24439](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/24439), the pull request introducing `unknown`.  And they work on unions.  So these look the same:

```
let value: string | number | boolean = 
  ["abc", 123, true][Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)];

if (!(typeof value === 'string') && !(typeof value === 'number')) {
  return false
}

value // string | number
```

and

```
let value: unknown = 
  ["abc", 123, true][Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)];

if (!(typeof value === 'string') && !(typeof value === 'number')) {
  return false
}

value // string | number
```

But [*assignment* narrowing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#assignments) doesn't narrow `unknown`.  Assignments first widen the variable back to its original type (so any prior narrowings will be reset) and then filters the variable to just those union members to which the new value is assignable.  It's like you're using [the `Extract<T, U>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#extracttype-union).

If you have a variable of type `string | number | boolean` and you assign a `string` to it, then the variable will be narrowed to `Extract<string | number | boolean, string>` which is `string`:

```
let value: string | number | boolean = "test";
value.toUpperCase(); // okay
```

But `unknown` is not a union, if you assign a `string` to it, the resulting type will be `Extract<unknown, string>` which is just `unknown`, and the compiler does not understand that it's a `string`:

```
let value: unknown = 'something' 
value.toUpperCase(); // error!
```

---

And this is responsible for the behavior you're seeing.  You can use `typeof` to narrow `unknown` to `string | number`, but when you do an assignment it gets widened back to `unknown`.  It is suggested at [microsoft/TypeScript#27706](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27706) that assignments to `unknown` variables should narrow.  If you agree you might want to give that issue a , but it's a fairly longstanding open issue so I wouldn't count on anything changing here soon.  (The recent [improvements to narrowing](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-8/#improved-intersection-reduction-union-compatibility-and-narrowing) don't seem to affect this.)

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.8.2#code/FAMwrgdgxgLglgewgAgKYA8CGBbADgG1QFUIBrCBAdwgAoBKALmQCMEFDMUBvYYZZQjGQA3TPjComkclRQBeZAHIAzgmyoYACzgQA5or4ixEgHQwERXLlQAnAMKZlqegG5kAendobNhDYCEhqLiqMgKANoARJjMUJEANMgAjABMAMyJMDYSALrhALKYWiYg+Gw2NIXFNpwAJmr0yABUyGl0OS68hnAgyDT+NDAAntYIvcESYXIKKlk6+nTIAGRLyAPDo+PGodMzEGDYzLaKdIs8-Pw2GmA2KCBiToYAvrz8E6GeyMpzesgAPsh9odbK8jCEwkoYKhvgYgtsPF5pBRqHCQmYLFZbA4nK5DFcYDcUFkJMAXrxwNB4Eg0Fg8IQSIhaIwWGwONxQYIwRImN8bPN-oCDkcbALWOxUJwISo1BptHoDG9tujLNZ7I5nHQ3J8EKRMENQe8IVEYnFEqkMshiag8lVNCUyn5KkU7TUIPVsI0Wm0OqCen11iNUGMuTtpkpefMTstVgHNiGpnshcdTshzhd8YTkPd8I9+GTFeDPhHfgCgcLUZMZlCYQb4Z8kbIK6hlZi1TjNXjrrdLdlUKTgEA)